# Memory not clearing after closing activity

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks

Having two simple activity without content. Navigation to 2nd activity using intent. When closing 2nd activity and 1st both then also its exists in memory.

If visiting 2nd time then 2 instance is available

Hi Please find below screenshot for Activity 1 & Activity 2 & Memory Profiler details

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide some code snippets. it seems you're facing memory leak

Comment: given screenshot in answer. Please check and help.

Comment: What language is this? C#? I don't see anything causing a memory leak. install LeakCanary for finding if any available.

Comment: Yes this is Xamarin Android. Installed LeakCanary this also showing leak sometime but not giving exact issue.